# Django admin: rendering a model field with options to multiple select checkbox

Tags: python, django, model

I want to render a model field as a checkbox so, that I have options predefined as a list of tuples, How do I do this?

```
class Car(models.Model):
    groups = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                              blank=False)

class CarAdmin(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['groups'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=CARS_ALLOWED)
```

Comment: Er, apart from the fact that you should use CheckboxInput rather than CheckboxSelectMultiple, you do it like that. What's the question?

Comment: What you have, didn't work? What's in `CARS_ALLOWED`?